# How can I rotate text by 90 degrees in LyX?

Tags: lyx

In Lyx, what are the different possibilities to rotate a selection of text by 90 degrees?

Comment: Typing `\rotatebox{90}{Foo}` perhaps? ;-) (Requires the `graphicx` package)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [new feature](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX.NewInLyX22) in LyX 2.2 (beta will be out soon if you would like to test):
Go to Document > Settings > Modules and add the GraphicBoxes module. Then go to Insert > Custom Insets > RotateBox

For more information, read the manuals. For example, this feature is described in section 5.8.1 of the Embedded Objects manual.

Note that it has been possible for a long time (I believe) to rotate table cells, floats, and other items, but for text it is new.